# Cross ratio of 5 coplanar points

Tags: projective-geometry, python, cross-ratio

I need to calculate cross ratio of 5 coplanar points. I have formula for one of the invariants. The problem is I don't know how can this be implemented in programming (in python). I've used dot product of matrices bu that is not giving a scalar value.

[image: cross ratio of 5 coplanar points]

PS: the screenshot is from this [paper](https://www.eurecom.fr/en/publication/3663/download/mm-publi-3663.pdf)

Comment: The numbers between the vertical bars define a determinant, not a matrix.

Comment: You can compute these determinants using the numpy function "numpy.linalg.det"

Comment: It is written "ratio of determinants" in your text (in the right column of page 2)... not "ratio of matrices".

Comment: c = (np.linalg.det(M_124) * np.linalg.det(M_135))/(np.linalg.det(M_125) * np.linalg.det(M_134))

where M_124 = np.array([[A[x], B[x], D[x]], [A[y], B[y], D[y]], [1, 1, 1]]) and so on..
is this correct?

Comment: Connected : https://www.mdpi.com/2075-1680/3/2/202

Comment: I am surprised that this formula uses parameter $1$ four times in the first rank, which means that $A$ is privilegized whereas the figure privilegizes point $E$ with index $5$ ...